# Orchard CMS with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

Does anyone know where I might find out when Orchard will be available with MVC 4.

I notice the roadmap includes this as the 'current priorities' but, when is v1.6 being released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.6 should be out in about a month. You can also clone the repo to the latest 1.x.

Comment: Is a list of the 1.6 features available or is this version just an upgrade to MVC 4?

Comment: It's upgrading dependencies, including nHibernate and MVC, fixing bugs and adding database caching, thus considerably improving performance.

Comment: I am new to Orchard - what is the best way to create a new Visual Studio solution with MVC 4 (Views/Controllers/Models folders etc) - with Orchard CMS installed?

Comment: That is an entirely new question, that shouldn't be in the comments of another, unrelated question.